# jquery: how to get html excluding a div in it?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

this is my html

```
loaded-data  = "
<div id='content'>
<div id='1'></div>
<div id='2'></div>
<div id='3'></div>
</div>"


var myHtml = $(data).find('#content').html(); // i get all 3 divs
```

what if i want to exlude div 3?

Comment: now that i think better my question could be: how can i select only the first 2 divs html?

Comment: The code in your question is inconsistent. To verify, is `loaded-data` a String? And is the `data` variable referencing the same string?

Comment: Also, could you please clarify that your intention is to get an HTML string that excludes the last `div`? Your intent isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't know that it's a good idea to start your ID's with numbers. It may be a holdover of my early VB6 programming days, but I always make id's something like `item1` and `item2`. That being said, if you want to selected the first two divs, try

```
$('#content #item1, #content #item2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Good solution, when you don't know ids of inner divs - will always work. You can additionally specify class in `children` method if nedded.

```
$('#content').children('div').slice(0, 2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems to imply that you're talking about a String. If so, select the [`children()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/children/)  and [`remove()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)  the one you don't want from the matched set by referencing the last one with the [`slice()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method .

Then use the [`end()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/end/) method to get back to the initial element.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/vhsA5/

```
var myHtml = $(data).children().slice(-1).remove().end().end().html();
```

---

**EDIT:** I'd note that if the HTML string you posted is a smaller part of a larger bit of HTML, you'll likely need to add the `.find('#content')` back in before `.children()`.

Answer (score -1):

maybe?
var myHtml = $(data).contents().find("#content").not("#3").html();